# Is PHP exec safe?

Tags: php, security, exec

I am trying to get exec working on a Windows server and receiving the error message "unable to fork". After googling the issue a bit, it seems the recommended fix is to give the IUSR account READ and EXECUTE permissions to c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe.

But that has got be a major security hole right? Is it safe? Is there another way to execute [from php] an exe residing on the server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It needs to execute cmd.exe because when the Windows PHP sees this:

```
exec("foo -bar -baz");
```

It calls this:

```
cmd /c foo -bar -baz
```

It's only a security hole if you let your user enter parameters.  I.E., you shouldn't do this:

```
// DO NOT DO THIS!
exec("foo -bar=" . $_GET['bar']);
```

Instead, you should sanitize your parameters with [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

```
// This is okay.  (Be sure foo.exe can handle unexpected input!)
exec("foo -bar=" . escapeshellarg($_GET['bar']));
```

Comment: The exec function is as safe as you make it. As long as you use the proper escaping functions like shown here, you'll be good.

Comment: While it is possible to make the script commands safe, a common attack vector is to upload a malicious script and use `exec` and similar functions to hack the server. As such, many shared hosting environments disable this and any other function that can run a shell argument.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should keep in mind is that creating a process under Windows incurs more overhead than it does on Unix-class operating systems. If you have a large number of users, repeatedly calling `exec()` could bog down the server. If you anticipate a heavy load on your server, you may want to consider having a worker process running continually as a [Windows service](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.win32service.php)

Comment: The same problem can occur on Windows and Linux.