# form input and shell commands

Tags: php, forms, shell

I have a php form that reads in 2 inputs from the user:  database name and directory.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
DB Name: <input type="text" name="dbname"><br>
Directory: <input type="text" name="dir"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

what I'm trying to do is, based on the user inputs, would for the dbname, execute a mysqldump to backup the database.  and for directory, execute a tar `-czvf $dir.tar.gz $dir.`

I have the following for the tar part:

```
$directory=$_POST["dir"];

$output = shell_exec('tar -czvf "{$directory}".tar.gz "{directory}"');
```

However, it's executed, but not the desired result. Please help. thanks

Comment: It would be useful to note that for obvious reasons shell_exec is most usually added to disabled_functions within the php.ini configuration. Might be a good place to look in this case.

Comment: Before you proceed please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295346/is-php-exec-safe

Answer (score 1):

send the arguments with quota so you should use it like

```
$directory=$_POST["dir"];
$output = shell_exec('tar -czvf "{$directory}"');
```