# Issue with PHP functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, configuration, settings

I am working on a Laravel project and have installed a third-party utility (wpscan) on a Ubuntu server. In the code, I am calling the third party app using a command line and exec() function as shown in the code below.

```
$command = "wpscan --url " . $Website->url . " --enumerate p " . "--output ". $filename . "  --format json";
exec($command);
```

On my local machine, it is working fine but on the server it is not working. From my perspective, it looks like "exec" command is not working but I checked in php.ini file and it is not listed under **disable_functions**
so it should be working fine.

Is there anyone who can tell me what's going wrong here?

Comment: what about the `wpscan` command though? is it available  on your server?

Answer (score 1):

Either the `wpscan`command isn't installed on your server or the `exec()` function is not allowed on your server.

`exec()` not being allowed on servers provided by external parties is a fairly common thing. `exec()` creates a potential security risk because you allow the webserver to execute commands on your server. If this command accepts any user input, you are doomed.

Another probable cause is that your webserver's user doesn't have the right permissions to execute `wpscan` or the output it to the `$filename` location.

#### Further reading

- [Is PHP exec safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295346/is-php-exec-safe)