# Trying to safely use the exec function of PHP to run a python script on a server

Tags: php, python, server

Referring to a comment from someone on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295346/is-php-exec-safe):

> While it is possible to make the script commands safe, a common attack vector is to upload a malicious script and use exec and similar functions to hack the server. As such, many shared hosting environments disable this and any other function that can run a shell argument.

Is this true? Is my server in risk of being attacked simply because I enable the php scripts to run the `exec()` method?

What can I do to prevent hackers from uploading files on my server? Or are there any other countermeasure that allows me to use the exec method safely?

Comment: The main worry about `exec()` is that you accept user input and integrate it into the command in some fashion. If you do not untaint or validate it carefully, you could end up running a destructive command that you would not wish to allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have a method for allowing users to upload files, you should be fine.

The way hackers would do this is uploading a .php file with a malicious `exec()`, then open the file via a web browser, thus executing the PHP code in the file, along with the `exec()` method.